# Install Indigo on Ubuntu 16.04 from source: can't build pcl_ros

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Indigo does not support debian packages for Ubuntu 16.04, I'm trying to build it from source following http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source
Everything goes well until I'm trying to build the catkin workspace. I can't build the pcl_ros package. The log is shown as below:

```
[ 25%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 25%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/build.make:443: recipe for target '/home/ziri/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pointcloud_to_image' failed
[ 25%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
make[2]: *** [/home/ziri/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pointcloud_to_image] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 25%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/build.make:443: recipe for target '/home/ziri/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/pcd_to_pointcloud' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ziri/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/pcd_to_pointcloud] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/all] Error 2
[ 25%] Built target nodelet_topic_tools_gencfg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/build.make:443: recipe for target '/home/ziri/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/pointcloud_to_pcd' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ziri/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/pointcloud_to_pcd] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/all] Error 2
[ 25%] Built target pcl_msgs_generate_messages_py
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems to be related with -lvtkproj4, so I've tried to install vtk, but nothing changes after that.
There are some related issues posted:
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1594
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=819741
Someone say it is due to the bug of vtk6.

Anyone can help me? Much appreciation!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243932/install-indigo-on-ubuntu-16.04-from-source:-can%27t-build-pcl_ros/) by [Baichuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28010/baichuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this same issue.  I used apt-get to install libpcl-dev, libvtk6.2 and libproj-dev.  Then, I followed the hacky symbolic linking trick mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979146/what-is-the-package-to-install-full-pcl-with-aptitude-and-does-prerequisites-com and was able to compile the package.  The code for creating the symbolic link is shown below:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonCore-6.2.so /usr/lib/libvtkproj4.so
```

If/when this doesn't work during runtime, I plan to build the pcl_ros without using rosinstall, but directly from source.  You can  augment the CMakeLists.txt to *not* use any of vtk packages as shown on the [ros-perception github](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/f8fee6128aff90e5a211506929287870a26978cf/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt).

---

Originally posted by [onasafari](https://answers.ros.org/users/36350/onasafari/) with karma: 26 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aureliokta](https://answers.ros.org/users/37979/aureliokta/) on 2021-01-09**:
similar issue, this solved it! Also need to :

ln -s /usr/lib/libvtkproj4.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkproj4-6.2.so.6.2.0

From:
https://answers.ros.org/question/366812/ubuntu-1604-kinetic-update-no-rule-to-make-target-libvtkproj/